# Does Neovim support vimball plugins?

Tags: neovim, vimball

I'm trying to install the last version of [netrw](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#NETRW), which is distributed as a **vimball** file, but can't find the way of doing it in Neovim. So far I've tried:

1. Unzip the file
2. Run:

```
:packadd vimball
```

3. Inside neovim, moved to the directory where the netrw.vba file is and run:

```
:vim netrw.vba
```

But I get the error message:

```
E683: File name missing or invalid pattern
```

My question is, does Neovim really has support to install vimball files? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is with your step 3. You need to *open* the vimball file in NeoVim and the command to do so is [`:e`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Ae) and not `:vim`.

[`:vim`](https://vimhelp.org/quickfix.txt.html#%3Avim) is actually a shorthand for `:vimgrep`, that's why your error message is talking about *"invalid pattern"*, it's expecting at least two arguments, one pattern and one base path where to run a recursive grep.

After loading the vimball package with `:packadd vimball` and opening the netrw vimball with `:e netrw.vba`, all you need is to run it with `:so %` to install it.

---

By default, the vimball plug-in will unpack the plug-in files directly under your `~/.config/nvim`. That's the older scheme pre-[Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) where you would merge all the plug-in files into a single directory, rather than update `'runtimepath'` to include the root directory of each of your plug-ins.

If you want to unpack the vimball into an alternate location, you can also call [`:UseVimball`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_vimball.txt.html#%3AUseVimball) directly instead of calling `:so %` after opening the `*.vba` inside NeoVim/Vim.

For example, to turn the netrw vimball into a NeoVim package:

```
:!mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/netrw/start/netrw
:UseVimball ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/netrw/start/netrw
```

(For Vim, you can do the same, just use `~/.vim/pack` on Linux/Mac/Unix or `$HOME/vimfiles/pack` on Windows as the base package directory.)

Comment: Thanks, that did it. By any chance do you know where is the package installed, and if there's a way I can control that?

Comment: @BobbyWan-Kenobi Just updated the answer to include information on where it's installed by default and instructions on how to install it to a different location, for example turning it into a NeoVim package.

Comment: If you want to reinstall it as a package, you can use [`:RmVimball`](https://vimhelp.org/pi_vimball.txt.html#%3ARmVimball) to first uninstall it from your main nvim directory. You need to open the `*.vba` file first to do so, then run the `:RmVimball` command from there.

Comment: Great update, I've been reading on my own and tried a variation of your solution: I used ``~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack`` as a **base directory**, which successfully installed the plugin. But ``:RmVimball`` doesn't work no matter which of these two directories the plugin is installed. Apparently the file ``~/.config/nvim/.VimballRecord`` should keep track of the files that are installed with any vimball, so they can be removed after. But this file is empty, and ``:RmVimball`` throws: ``***vimball*** (RmVimball) unable to find <netrw.vba.gz> in .VimballRecord``

Comment: @BobbyWan-Kenobi ah yes that's the correct package directory in NeoVim! I'll update the answer with that. Yeah I saw `:RmVimball` is supposed to keep a "registry" but not sure if that really works as described... In any case, it shouldn't be too hard to uninstall by hand. In most cases, I'd expect your `~/.config/nvim` should be mostly empty other than `init.vim` anyways...

Comment: Yeah, mostly empty, and I wanted to keep it that way )) What I found, it's that contrary to the manual page, another ``.VimballRecord`` file is created and updated at the end of this path, next to the ``plugin`` folder, and it's correctly updated with the paths to whatever is installed. So I wonder if ``:RmVimball`` is intended to be used another way?